# Converting a raster file to a format supported by QField

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, qfield

We plan to use QField via a tablet in the field. Our project covers an area of ​​approx. 8000 ha. In QGIS we use our own older aerial photos as well as a WMS server. Is it possible to convert the aerial photos that are on our hard drive into a file format supported by QField so that we can also use the aerial photos on the tablet? The raster files are available to us as files with the .sid extension. A conversion is generally possible, but I don't know if the georeferencing information would be lost as a result of the conversion.

Comment: Have you tried creating a QField project. I regularly use raster (TIF, pdf and jpg I think) in QField. Give it a go. Then come back with specific questions.

Comment: I use geopackage format. Small size and fast

Answer (score 1):

See Documentation on supported data types and advice on raster formats here https://docs.qfield.org/reference/data-format/